# In python how can I convert regex match type (sre.SRE_Match) to FLOATS?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

New here. I am trying to learn python so that I can process .txt files that some of our hardware produces.  I have edited the original since it I was not entirely clear in the original question (not least  by mixing up intigers and floats).

The first 6-7 lines of the files contain some numerical information I need to extract.  The text file presents the information in the following format

> FR= 65 Left Marker Time=0.247000 Right Marker Time=1.606000

From which I need to extract the 0.247 and 1.606 as floats so I can use them in clalculations.  I can use regex to find the data I need (left and right  times), but I am unable to declare the resulting matches as floats for later use.

The code below returns matches as '_sre.SRE_Match'

```
import re

with open('strain1.txt') as f:
   data = f.read(200) #data is in the first few lines.
   start_time = re.compile (r'(?<=Left Marker Time=)\d*\.\d{4,7}')
   matches1 = start_time.finditer(data)
   for match in matches1:
   x = match
   print(type(x))
f.close()
```

If i try a simple conversion (e.g. x = int(match)) I get

> int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not '_sre.SRE_Match'

so I assume the search itself needs to be different somehow, and I think the problem is related to my use of 'finditer' only returning strings (?) but at this point im stuck?

Note: The search terms seem fine since if I change the last lines to

```
for match in matches1:
print(match)
```

I get

> _sre.SRE_Match object; span=(69, 77), match='0.247000'>

Update: If I use findall

```
start_time= re.findall (r'(?<=Left Marker Time=)\d*\.\d{4,7}', data)
```

and then query start time

```
print(start_time)
```

it is a list with a single string

```
['0.247000']
```

If I then try to map to a float

```
map(float, start_time)
```

I still get a string list

```
['0.247000']
```

Comment: `match.group()` ?

Comment: Or even `results = re.findall(r'Left Marker Time=(\d*\.\d{4,7})', data)`

Comment: Thanks - I did read similar answers but being a simpleton I did not understand where to put the commands into my code ;)   For anyone looking for the same answer Wiktor was correct I essentially replaced the compile line and the finditer lines with>>          start_time= re.findall (r'(?<=Left Marker Time=)\d*\.\d{4,7}', data)

Comment: I spoke too soon - In my code above findall seems to make a single item list which remains a string not an integer.  Also I realised I meant float not integer (since these all have decimal points).